# Proteus - connectivity highlights - void

Tags: proteus

When I click on connectivity_highlights/void I get some pads highlighted. What does this mean?

Comment: It's probably worth adding some further information and an image of the pads. I'm not familiar with  Proteus but it sounds a bit like a copper area may be too small, maybe the hole size is too large compared to the outside ring of the pads?

Comment: It's surface mount and as far as I can tell the component and layout is similar to another area that isn't flagged. Some component size, track widths, spacing from other components etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is a "Connectivity Status" box at the bottom of the Ares screen. When I click that, the problem goes away

Answer (score 0):

It not only highlights pads but vias  too. This can be used to verify routed connection.It can help in finding unrouted connections, you are required to double click the net from the list and it will highlight the connection. Hope it helps.

Comment: No vias involved. It's all top copper. From one pad of a DIL socket to a SM capacitor.

Comment: Wondering whether some back propagation problem from Ares to Isis since I get a "FAIL: Uncommitted netlist changes detected" on the pre-production tool